# Menu auto enable not working with a NSTabView

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-bindings

I have a todo-application that has a NSTabView with four NSTabViewItems. Each tab view has a view with a matching view controller all in separate nib-files. I have set the File Owner of each nib to be the view controller and the view outlets to their respective views.

I have patched the view controllers in the responder chain after its view and I have also set the view controllers nextResponder so the responder chain is intact. I have bound the Edit-menu items to First Responder actions. The problem is that when the application launches with the first tab selected, all Edit-menu items are enabled and work fine. But if i switch to another tab item and then back to the first tab item, all the Edit-menu items are disabled and nothing I do can make them enabled again. Any idea what's going on?

Answer (score 0):

The answer to my problem is that, the responder chain is intact after launch (View -> MyViewController -> NextResponder) and thus the menu-items work as expected. But when I change tabs on the NSTabView, the tab view will patch the corresponding NSTabViewItem.view into the responder chain creating View -> NextResponder and so the MyController gets left out of the chain and the menu commands no longer work. In other words the NSTabView resets the nextResponder of its view when changing tabs, leaving the controller out of the responder chain.

I simply made my controllers subclass NSView and set those to be the view of each NSTabViewItem. Now everything works fine.